# Is validation in react native dangerous?

Tags: react-native

I have done some validation in my react native code, but I want to ask about the possibility of that someone manipulating my code written in react native and installed on their mobile. Is it possible to happen like it happens with websites?

Comment: Everything (including the executable binary file) can be changed. Only server-side validation is valid (until vulnerable access is obtained to the server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should always have server side validations in place. If you are worried about someone viewing your javascript code then yes it is possible. Even easier they can intercept any server calls you make through the application and change whatever values you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

Everything (including the executable binary file) can be changed. Only server-side validation is valid (until vulnerable access is obtained to the server).